# Get value of dynamic nested checkbox in angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have created the dynamic nested checkboxes in Angular, I want to get the value of checkboxes if selected. I created a demo project in angular and facing the problem in json structure to achieve functionality.

[image: screenshot]

[sourcecode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g3qbrt?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more effective solution, but I would make an object with nested objects that are connected to your html.

For example:

```
countriesSport: CountrySports[] | undefined;

country: { id: 1, name: England, active: false, sports: [{ id: 1, name: soccer, active: false, selection: ENUM girl|boy|all}]}
```

You can save these values in a variable in your .ts file. In your html you can map over these values, for example like this:

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let country of countries>
         <input 
         type="checkbox"
        name="checkbox"
        [checked]="country.active"
        (change)="functionToDoExtraTHingsLikeToggleSubItems()"
    />
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let sport of country.sports>
             <input 
         type="checkbox"
    name="checkbox"
    [checked]="sport.active"
    (change)="functionToChangeSportsStuff()"
    />
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

How you want to structure and style you input fields and which onces can be chosen or not, depends on your demands. The selection ENUM with girls|boys|all can also be an array of objects that has an active state.

When you initialize and destroy you component, you can save or map your object to other values.